# How to Write to AVI with OpenCV Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, opencv, ffmpeg

### I want to write properly formed frames of video data to an AVI.

All attempts fail.

What I end up with, after long efforts of debugging, are *.avi files of non-zero length in the desired directory, which will not play with any of multiple video players already installed on my system.

Please note:  High quality answers will be COMPLETE and DETAIL oriented.  In particular, questions about writing video with OpenCV tend to generate drive-by responses including little more than another four-letter code to stick in `fourcc`.  Answers which do so without also telling me at a minimum what file extension to use, what file type it will generate, and why it is expected to work over what I give above are unhelpful.

### Here are the salient details of the system:

Operating System:  Windows 10
Language:  Python 3.7, with Anaconda 3
OpenCV:  4.1.0

### Here Is What I Have Done/Tried:

Installed FFMPEG as per [this link](http://kronoskoders.logdown.com/posts/256664-installing-opencv-and-ffmpeg-on-windows), restarted Anaconda, and verified ffmpeg (`ffmpeg -version`) from within Anaconda, with the following result:

```
ffmpeg version N-94396-g47b6ca0b02 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190716
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
libavutil      56. 32.100 / 56. 32.100
libavcodec     58. 55.100 / 58. 55.100
libavformat    58. 30.100 / 58. 30.100
libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
libavfilter     7. 58.100 /  7. 58.100
libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
```

Multiple variations on the theme of:

```
import cv2
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"DIVX")
vidout = cv2.VideoWriter(baseDir + "videos\\foo.avi", fourcc, 30, (530, 476))

for frame in frames:
    <do stuff to generate foo>
    cv2.imshow("foo", foo)
    vidout.write(foo)
vidout.release()
```

Verified shape, dtype, and general viability of output data with `cv2.imshow("foo", foo)`

### Results: Unplayable AVI files

Answer (score 0):

i don't really get what you want to do but i have a code in my virtual assistant that records a video using opencv (cv2 library) and saves it as .avi (without audio for opencv doesn't support that) using python 3.6

```
import cv2

def main():
    window_name = "Eri is recording this!"
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    filename = "F:\\Video.avi"
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("X", "V", "I", "D")
    frame_rate = 30
    resolution = (640, 480)
    Output = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, frame_rate, resolution)
    if cap.isOpened():
       ret, frame = cap.read()
    else:
       ret = False

    while ret:
       ret, frame = cap.read()

       Output.write(frame)

       cv2.imshow(window_name, frame)
       if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
          break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    Output.release()
    cap.release()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

hope this helps. PS. if you have any errors trying my code. just tell me. it's working 101% right now PS2. Change the value of "filename" variable to your desired path where you want to save the video. You can only save literally one video. this means that if you dont copy or rename the previous video you captured by this, it will be overwritten. press ESC key to end the stream

Answer (score 0):

### Things I Tried:

> Verified shape, dtype, and general viability of output data with cv2.imshow("foo", foo)

Well apparently not.

`cv2.imshow("foo", foo)`has no expectations I know of on the first two dimensions of the shape of the object foo, i.e., rows and columns.

However, if `foo.shape` is (x, y, channels) then the writer needs to be defined as:

```
vidout = cv2.VideoWriter(baseDir + "videos\\foo.avi", fourcc, 30, (y, x))
```

Note the transposition of x and y.

So you can generate all the frames of data you want, send them to `cv2.imshow(foo)` for verification, manually get the shape of your data with `foo.shape`, naively put the shape as reported into the VideoWriter setup, and run it.  The software will run without any complaint at all.  It will generate an AVI file as specified.  And the AVI file will be unplayable garbage.

Brilliant.